# Run the remote script in linux without login

Tags: php, linux, remote-access, remote-execution

I am having one php script in remote linux server. I need to run that php from another linux machine without any kind of login.

In Linux Machine 1:

```
$] /home/user/myScript.php
```

In Linux Machine 2:

```
$] runRemoteCmd linuxMachine1:/home/regress/myScript.php
...
      myScript.php outputs
...
```

I need something like this.

Answer (score 3):

You need to have the script on the remote server, and if you have ssh key authentication you can do the following

```
ssh user@thatServer.toruncommand.com 'command to run'
```

Comment: Hi Chris, I don't want to do any kind of login in this case.

Comment: @Ashwin could you please explain more in detail what you mean but not wanting to login? If you mean not needing to authenticate on each connection then look up what mentioned and check out ssh keys.

Comment: @Ashwin using public key authentication you won't need a password.  You should still have some kind of authentication but ssh key auth won't require a password unless you put a password on the key.

Comment: I do not want to do any kind of login directly/indirectly. ie. I even don't want to use ssh keygen to store keys. It should work like the webpages, with any new systems also but without any kind of security tuning.